# Where is the GIT (or other) repo for the Ubuntu (or Linux) man pages?

Tags: repository, manpage, source

I don't know whether all of the man pages are under the same source control repository or not; specifically, I'm interested in the Vim man pages source.

Where can I find the source control repository for the text behind `man vim`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [vim site](https://vim.sourceforge.io/git.php): Vim has a GitHub repository at https://github.com/vim/vim.

The man pages are in https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/vim.man.

Answer (score 1):

They're not all under the same repository. Manpages are provided by various packages, usually a package only provides manpages for the commands, libraries etc. provided by it.

To see what package a manpage comes from:

```
$ man -w vim
/usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
$ dpkg -S $(!!)                                     
dpkg -S $(man -w vim)
vim-common: /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
$ apt-cache show vim-common | grep Source
Source: vim
```

Now you can browse the packaging information at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim (which includes the code for packaging, which should tell you where the upstream source is). In general, it's not easy to obtain the upstream source repository directly.

The upstream source of Vim is on GitHub now, so you can browse the source used to generate these manpages there: https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/doc/

Comment: Very thorough response, thanks! I arbitrarily chose to accept Jos' answer as it came through earlier and was accurate, but yours has taught me a lot as well.